# How to retrieve an object's Property name/value pairs on a custom object?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a custom object with varying datatypes for each property.
I would like to be able to do something like:

```
    public void evalCI(configurationItem CI)
     {
    foreach (PropertyInformation n in CI)
       {
        Response.Write(n.Name.ToString() + ": " + n.Value.ToString() + "</br>");
       }
     }
```

My custom object is:

```
public class configurationItem : IEnumerable

{
    private string serial;
    private string model;
    private DateTime? wstart;
    private DateTime? wend;
    private Int32 daysLeft;
    private string platform;
    private string productVersion;
    private string manufacturer;
    private bool verificationFlag;        

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }

    public string Serial
    {
        set { serial = value; }
        get { return serial; }
    }
    public string Model
    {
        set { model = value; }
        get { return model; }
    }
    public DateTime? Wstart
    {
        set { wstart = value; }
        get { return wstart; }
    }
    public DateTime? Wend
    {
        set { wend = value; }
        get { return wend; }
    }
    public Int32 DaysLeft
    {
        set { daysLeft = value; }
        get { return daysLeft; }
    }
    public string Platform
    {
        set { platform = value; }
        get { return platform; }
    }
    public string ProductVersion
    {
        set { productVersion = value; }
        get { return productVersion; }
    }
    public string Manufacturer
    {
        set { manufacturer = value; }
        get { return manufacturer; }
    }
    public bool VerificationFlag
    {
        set { verificationFlag = value; }
        get { return verificationFlag; }
    }
```

My expected output would be:

-Serial: 1234567

-Model: Mustang

-Wstart: 12/12/2005

-Wend: 12/11/2006

-DaysLeft: 0

-Platform: Car

-ProductVersion: GT

-Manufacturer: Ford

-VerificationFlag: true

At first I was getting an error that GetEnumerator() had to be implemented to use a foreach loop.  The problem I keep running into is that all of the examples of Indexed Properties are of a single property with an indexable list, instead of an index for each property in the object. I was able to get intellisense to give me methods for PropertyInfo by adding:

```
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }
```

However, the 2nd GetEnumerator() throws:
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'GetEnumerator' does not exist in the current context.

What am I missing here? How do I modify my object to give me the results I expect from evalCI()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement IEnumerable.  What you do need to do is use Reflection.

This is from memory, but I believe it would look like this:

```
   foreach (PropertyInfo n in typeof(configurationItem).GetProperties())
   {
     Response.Write(string.Format("{0}:  {1}<br/>", n.Name, n.GetValue(CI, null)));
   }
```

This - the code as written - will also only give you public properties, and non-indexed properties (but it doesn't look like you have any indexed properties).

Comment: That brings me to :  CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PropertyInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: PropertyInfo was fine in the original foreach.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are missing a `using` directive, as it says:  add `using System.Reflection;` to your `using` statements.

Comment: PropertyInfo was in another namespace. So it compiles but I am getting the null reference exception now .

Comment: Well, as I suggested, this is probably due to attempting a ToString on a property for which the value is null.  I will modify the snippet a little to avoid that problem.

Comment: OK, edited.  This should handle null property values.  (Also, I am assuming that CI actually has a value.  If it doesn't, you probably will still get the null ref exception.)

Comment: Thanks! I got the null sorted.